# How to save full console OUTPUT in R every time RStudio is exited?

Tags: r, console, save

The title says it all.
Tried `history()` and it only went back very few lines, but I want to see my progress from the first lines of the project.
How can console in R be saved so that everytime it opens where things were left off?

Comment: See `?savehistory`.

Comment: According to the `?history` help page, there is to limit on the size of the history stored, but when you call `history()` it will only show the last 25 by default. Have you tried `savehistory()` to write out everything?

Comment: Or just try `history(1000)`